# Как проверить что пароль от sudo верен?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, sh, sudo

В моем `python` скрипте есть строка; я хочу проверить, что она является верным паролем для `sudo`, чтобы запустить системную команду. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo -v` решает эту задачу. Например

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


password = input()
proc = Popen(["sudo", "-v", "-S"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE).communicate(input=password + "\n\n\n")
if len(popen[1].decode()) == 0:
    print("password correct")
else:
    print("Forbidden")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sudo_is_true(password):
    answer = os.popen(f'echo {password} | sudo -S echo "hello"').read().strip()
    return answer == 'hello'
```

Comment: В этом ответе есть проблема. Отсутствует экранирование спецсимволов в пароле.